# Unique ID in ArcMap 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table, unique-id

In an attribute table, how should I go about adding a Unique ID into a field? For example, I have a Water Meter points layer with an attribute table but I need a field that list them numerically with WM attached to the numbers. I would like to have a field displaying WM1001, WM1002, etc. Is there any way to accomplish this? Thanks.